# connecion with statconnDCOM connector

Tags: r

I try to create a connection between R and an other software by using the R connector: statconnDCOM but it dosen't work.
Under R 3.1.0 I called the following packages:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(rscproxy)
```

Then I tested the connection with statconnDCOM and I got the following error:

```
Loading 32 Bit StatConnector Server... Done
Initializing R...Function call failed
Code: -2147221485
Text: installation problem: unable to load connector
Releasing StatConnector Server...Done
```